# How can I access a certain JSON element that may not always be in the same location?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the below JSON returned from an API, what is the best way in Ruby to retrieve the `value` element from (and only from) the array element with `"detail_type": "SubTotalLineDetail"`? In this case, the value 1005.

The issue arises in that the subtotal line item location is not fixed to always be the second to last line item, it is most often in the last position, but, as shown in the example, that can change, so my attempted `i.sub_total = invoice[:line_items].last[:amount]` doesn't always work.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "line_num": 1,
        "description": "Custom Design",
        "amount": "300.0",
        "detail_type": "SalesItemLineDetail",
        "sales_line_item_detail": {
            "item_ref": {
                "value": "4",
                "name": "Design",
                "type": null
            },
            "class_ref": null,
            "unit_price": "75.0",
            "rate_percent": null,
            "price_level_ref": null,
            "quantity": "4.0",
            "tax_code_ref": {
                "value": "NON",
                "name": null,
                "type": null
            },
            "service_date": null,
            "tax_inclusive_amount": null
        },
        "sub_total_line_detail": null,
        "payment_line_detail": null,
        "discount_line_detail": null,
        "group_line_detail": null,
        "description_line_detail": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "line_num": null,
        "description": null,
        "amount": "1005.0",
        "detail_type": "SubTotalLineDetail",
        "sales_line_item_detail": null,
        "sub_total_line_detail": {
            "item_ref": null,
            "class_ref": null,
            "unit_price": null,
            "quantity": null,
            "tax_code_ref": null
        },
        "payment_line_detail": null,
        "discount_line_detail": null,
        "group_line_detail": null,
        "description_line_detail": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "line_num": null,
        "description": null,
        "amount": "50.25",
        "detail_type": "DiscountLineDetail",
        "sales_line_item_detail": null,
        "sub_total_line_detail": null,
        "payment_line_detail": null,
        "discount_line_detail": {
            "discount_ref": null,
            "percent_based": true,
            "discount_percent": "5.0",
            "discount_account_ref": {
                "value": "86",
                "name": "Discounts given",
                "type": null
            },
            "class_ref": null,
            "tax_code_ref": null
        },
        "group_line_detail": null,
        "description_line_detail": null
    }
]
```

Comment: You could simply iterate to find that `Hash`. Given your current `Array` as `a`, `a.find {|h| h["detail_type"] == "SubTotalLineDetail" }["amount"]`

Comment: @engineersmnky Yep, works perfectly, feel silly for not thinking of that sooner. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```rb
array.filter_map {|x| x[:amount].to_f if x[:detail_type].eql?('SubTotalLineDetail') }
```

If you want to sum it

```rb
array.filter_map {|x| x[:amount].to_f if x[:detail_type].eql?('SubTotalLineDetail') }.sum
```